# Need for MSCK REPAIR TABLE on a dependent table every hour

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, aws-glue

I have two AWS Glue jobs:

1. Job1: This job loads data into Hive Table A, which is partitioned on date. It runs every hour.
2. Job2: This job sources data from Hive Table A and loads it into Hive Table B. It runs every hour after Job1 completes.

My question is, do I need to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE command on Table A before Job2 runs every hour to ensure the partitions are correctly detected and loaded into Table B? or does Job2 automatically handle this process?

Any insights or best practices regarding this setup would be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: How are the new partitions in table a created and loaded?  If it's done through Hive, you don't have to do anything.  If you are creating partitions (directories) and writing data using Spark, then you may have to run msck repair when you create a new partition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The new partitions on Table A are created by Glue job Job1.

Comment: @Andrew - Considering the job runs every run, won't one msck repair table be enough to have the metadata refreshed as the hourly run loads to same date partition? Rather than having it done every hour.

Comment: Yes, you would only need to run it when you add a partition.  No need if you are only adding data to an existing partition